# Windows 8 kind of transition effect in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I have seen the animation which happens in windows 8 when we click on a tile (while moving to next screen). Is there any way to achieve similar type of animation in android native application?

Comment: Not sure in android. but possible through JQuery  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015807/emulating-windows-8-live-tiles-animation-with-jquery-how-to-start-animation-fas